# Sounds like Ohio Buckeye

Tags: sports

I had a friend in high school whose mother came from Japan.  I remember she told us that her mother laughed whenever anyone mentioned the OSU team, Ohio Buckeyes. I remember Ohio sounds like the word for Good morning, but I can't remember what "Buckeye" sounds like.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

In an American accent, I guess it may quite likely have been

> Ohio Buckeye ≓ おはようバカ = good morning idiot(s)

Comment: that'd would be really funny!

Comment: This reminded me also of the word in Filipino for cow/beef which is "baka" (similar to Spanish "vaca") and the Japanese would always have a good laugh.

Comment: @rebuuilt FWIW there's a viral recipe called [バカのアホ炒め](https://mitok.info/?p=103992).

Comment: And I always laugh when hearing "Chips Ahoy".